# laravel更新機能を作成、どの編集ボタンを押しても同じ表示内容が表示される、また更新すると他の投稿を含めたすべての値が更新される。

Tags: laravel

laravel更新機能を作成後、例えば投稿①と投稿②それぞれ違う内容を投稿、一覧ページでも違う内容として表示されていますが、投稿ごとに設置した編集ボタンを押すと、すべて①の内容が表示されます。その後投稿①のIDの内容を更新すると、②を含めたすべてのIDの値が更新されてしまいます。
お手数ですが、教えて頂きたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

GradeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Grade;

class GradeController extends Controller
{
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function postpage (Request $request){
        return view ('student.grade');
       }
       
    public function savenew (Request $request){
        // 
       }
    public function index()
    {
        $grades=Grade::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        $user=auth()->user();
        return view('student.index2', compact('grades','user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('student.grade');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $inputs=$request->validate([
            'grade'=>'required|max:255',
            'term'=>'required|max:255',
            'japanese'=>'required|max:255',
            'math'=>'required|max:255',
            'science'=>'required|max:255',
            'social_studies'=>'required|max:255',
            'music'=>'required|max:255',
            'home_economics'=>'required|max:255',
            'english'=>'required|max:255',
            'art'=>'required|max:255',
            'health_and_physical_education'=>'required|max:255',
        ]);

        $grade=new grade();
        $grade->grade = $request->grade;
        $grade->term = $request->term;
        $grade->japanese = $request->japanese;
        $grade->math = $request->math;
        $grade->science = $request->science;
        $grade->social_studies = $request->social_studies;
        $grade->music = $request->music;
        $grade->home_economics = $request->home_economics;
        $grade->english = $request->english;
        $grade->art = $request->art;
        $grade->health_and_physical_education = $request->health_and_physical_education;
        $grade->save();
        return back()->with('message','投稿を作成しました');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Grade $grade)
    {
        $grades=Grade::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        $user=auth()->user();
        return view('student.show2', compact('grades','user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Grade $grade)
    {
        return view('student.edit2', compact('grade'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Grade $grade)
    {
        $inputs=$request->validate([
            'grade'=>'required|max:255',
            'term'=>'required|max:255',
            'japanese'=>'required|max:255',
            'math'=>'required|max:255',
            'science'=>'required|max:255',
            'social_studies'=>'required|max:255',
            'music'=>'required|max:255',
            'home_economics'=>'required|max:255',
            'english'=>'required|max:255',
            'art'=>'required|max:255',
            'health_and_physical_education'=>'required|max:255',
        ]);

        $grade->grade = $inputs['grade'];
        $grade->term = $inputs['term'];
        $grade->japanese = $inputs['japanese'];
        $grade->math = $inputs['math'];
        $grade->science = $inputs['science'];
        $grade->social_studies = $inputs['social_studies'];
        $grade->music = $inputs['music'];
        $grade->home_economics = $inputs['home_economics'];
        $grade->english = $inputs['english'];
        $grade->art = $inputs['art'];
        $grade->health_and_physical_education = $inputs['health_and_physical_education'];
        $grade->save();
        return back()->with('message','投稿を更新しました');
      
    
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

edit2.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 mt-6">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="mt4">成績編集</h1>
          @if ($errors->any())
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <ul>
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
          @endforeach
          </ul>
          </div>
           @endif
            @if(session('message'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">{{session('message')}}</div>
            @endif
            <form method="post" action="{{route('grade.update',$grade)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @method('put')
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="grade">学年</label>
                    <input type="text" name="grade" class="form-control" 
                    id="grade" value="{{old('grade',$grade->grade)}}" placeholder="grade">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="term">学期</label>
                    <input type="text" name="term" class="form-control"
                     id="term" value="{{old('term',$grade->term)}}" placeholder="term">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="japanese">国語</label>
                    <input type="text" name="japanese" class="form-control" 
                    id="japanese" value="{{old('japanese',$grade->japanese)}}" placeholder="japanese">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="math">数学</label>
                    <input type="text" name="math" class="form-control" 
                    id="math" value="{{old('math',$grade->math)}}" placeholder="math">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="science">理科</label>
                    <input type="text" name="science" class="form-control" 
                    id="science" value="{{old('science',$grade->science)}}" placeholder="science">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="social_studies">社会</label>
                    <input type="text" name="social_studies" class="form-control" 
                    id="social_studies" value="{{old('social_studies',$grade->social_studies)}}"  placeholder="social_studies">
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="music">音楽</label>
                    <input type="text" name="music" class="form-control" id="music" value="{{old('music',$grade->music)}}" placeholder="music">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="home_economics">家庭科</label>
                    <input type="text" name="home_economics" class="form-control" 
                    id="home_economics" value="{{old('home_economics',$grade->home_economics)}}"placeholder="home_economics">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="english">英語</label>
                    <input type="text" name="english" class="form-control" 
                    id="english" value="{{old('english',$grade->english)}}" placeholder="english">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="art">美術</label>
                    <input type="text" name="art" class="form-control" 
                    id="art" value="{{old('art',$grade->art)}}" placeholder="art">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="health_and_physical_education">保健体育</label>
                    <input type="text" name="health_and_physical_education" class="form-control" 
                    id="health_and_physical_education" value="{{old('health_and_physical_education',$grade->health_and_physical_education)}}"placeholder="health_and_physical_education">
                </div>
                

                <x-button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">編集</x-button>
                <x-button type="button" onclick="history.back()">戻る</x-button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

show2.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
{{-- 投稿一覧表示用のコード --}}
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    @foreach($grades as $grade)
    <div class="mx-4 sm:p-8">
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <div class="bg-white w-full  rounded-2xl px-10 py-8 shadow-lg hover:shadow-2xl transition duration-500">
                        <div class="mt-4">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->grade }}</h1>
                            
                            <a href="{{route('grade.edit', $grade)}}"><x-button class="bg-teal-700 float-right">編集</x-button></a>
                            </h1><hr class="w-full">
                            <hr class="w-full">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->term }}</h1>
                            <hr class="w-full">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->japanese }}</h1>
                            <hr class="w-full">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->math }}</h1>
                            <hr class="w-full">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->science }}</h1>
                            <hr class="w-full">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->social_studies }}</h1>
                            <hr class="w-full">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->music }}</h1>
                            <hr class="w-full">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->home_economics }}</h1>
                            <hr class="w-full">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->english }}</h1>
                            <hr class="w-full">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->art }}</h1>
                            <hr class="w-full">
                            <h1 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold hover:underline cursor-pointer"> {{ $grade->health_and_physical_education }}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endsection
```

grade.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 mt-6">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="mt4">成績登録</h1>
          @if ($errors->any())
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <ul>
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
          @endforeach
          </ul>
          </div>
           @endif
            @if(session('message'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">{{session('message')}}</div>
            @endif
            <form method="post" action="{{route('grade.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="grade">学年</label>
                    <input type="text" name="grade" class="form-control" id="grade" value="{{old('grade')}}" placeholder="grade">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="term">学期</label>
                    <input type="text" name="term" class="form-control" id="term" value="{{old('term')}}" placeholder="term">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="japanese">国語</label>
                    <input type="text" name="japanese" class="form-control" id="japanese" value="{{old('japanese')}}" placeholder="japanese">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="math">数学</label>
                    <input type="text" name="math" class="form-control" id="math" value="{{old('math')}}" placeholder="math">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="science">理科</label>
                    <input type="text" name="science" class="form-control" id="science" value="{{old('science')}}" placeholder="science">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="social_studies">社会</label>
                    <input type="text" name="social_studies" class="form-control" id="social_studies" value="{{old('social_studies')}}"  placeholder="social_studies">
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="music">音楽</label>
                    <input type="text" name="music" class="form-control" id="music" value="{{old('music')}}" placeholder="music">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="home_economics">家庭科</label>
                    <input type="text" name="home_economics" class="form-control" id="home_economics" value="{{old('home_economics')}}"placeholder="home_economics">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="english">英語</label>
                    <input type="text" name="english" class="form-control" id="english" value="{{old('english')}}" placeholder="english">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="art">美術</label>
                    <input type="text" name="art" class="form-control" id="art" value="{{old('art')}}" placeholder="art">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="health_and_physical_education">保健体育</label>
                    <input type="text" name="health_and_physical_education" class="form-control" id="health_and_physical_education" value="{{old('health_and_physical_education')}}"placeholder="health_and_physical_education">
                </div>
                

                <x-button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">登録</x-button>
                <x-button type="button" onclick="history.back()">戻る</x-button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\StudentController;
use App\Http\Controllers\GradeController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

//Route::get('/', function () {
//    return view('welcome');
//});

Route::get('/student1', function () {
    return view('student');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

Route::resource('/student', StudentController::class);

Route::get('/student2', [StudentController::class,'show']);

Route::resource('/grade', GradeController::class);

Route::get('/grade2', [GradeController::class,'show']);
```